# In SAS compute an md5 hash for whole file given you have an md5 hash for each record

Tags: sas, md5, checksum

This is a follow-up to my recent question on calculating md5 hash in SAS and python. So, I'm using SAS v9.2 and there is an md5 hash function which takes in a string and returns a hash. What I'd really like though is a way to compute the hash for the file as a whole. Given that I have a hash for each record , is there any way to do this and have the file hash match up with the value obtained by using , say, python code.  Taking the sashelp.shoes dataset as an example I exported this to a CSV file and manually removed double quotes and dollars and commas of the currency fields. I then computed the hash for the file as a whole using this python code:

```
filename = "f:/test/shoes.csv"
md5_hash = hashlib.md5()
with open(filename,"rb") as f:
    # Read and update hash string value in blocks of 4K
    for byte_block in iter(lambda: f.read(1024*1024),b''):
        md5_hash.update(byte_block.replace(b'\r', b'').replace(b'\n', b''))
    print(md5_hash.hexdigest())
```

And got this hash back as output:

```
f7f205b5b844bf57f5f51685969e0df0
```

If anyone can replicate this final hash value in SAS for that dataset that would be great.

PS I'm on SAS V9.2

Comment: If your file is smaller than 32k bytes you could do it within a regular datastep as character variables are (still!) limited to 32767 chars.  Otherwise you may be able to do this with `proc ds2` which allows more data types (including longer strings).

Answer (score 1):

My earlier note on limitations applies only when working with DS1. There is no way around the length restriction in DS1. You could try this and you will get an error:

```
data test;
  length x $30000;
  x = repeat('-', 30000);
run;

data _null_;
  set test;
  format m $hex32.;
  m = md5(catx(',', x, x));
  put m=;
run;`
```

But Robert Pendridge is correct to point out that DS2 can solve this issue.

```
%let reclen = 201; /* Length of each record */
%let records = 2000; /* Number of records */
%let totlen = %eval(&reclen * &records);

proc ds2;
data _null_;
   retain m;
   dcl char(&totlen) m;
   method run();
      dcl char(200) c;
      set shoes;
      c = catx(',',&varstr2);
      m = strip(m)|| strip(c);
   end;
   method term();
      dcl char(32) hh;
      hh = put(md5(m), $hex32.);
      put hh=;
   end;
enddata;
run;
quit;
```

This is essentially doing what the Python code is doing. The `update` merely concatenates the strings and applies the hash. You may have to tighten this up a little bit to remove any extraneous spaces etc., but should work.

Comment: Inspiring trial, but definitely wrong: you neglect line separators.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Implement the MD5 algorithm in SAS. I'm aware of existing implementations for SHA and CRC but I'm not sure about MD5.
- Call an external utility from SAS to calculate the md5 hash for the file. There is an example [here](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/How-would-I-do-a-checksum-of-a-SAS-program-code-file/td-p/490234).

Comment: The second choice isn't an option as that would give me a hash for the SAS internal format of the dataset. The data in the dataset will ultimately be transferred as a text file to AWS. I wanted the hash in order to check that the data  we extract from SAS and what ends up in AWS is the same. As to your first point, SAS already has an MD5 function. However it only operates on a character string. I can compute the md5 hash for each line of the dataset. I wondered if I could you use that somehow to compute an md5 hash for the dataset as a whole

Comment: Are you more concerned about differences between the data extracted from SAS and the original SAS dataset, or about errors introduced in transit to AWS? You can rule out the latter much more easily by hashing the exported file before and after upload using an external utility.

Comment: @user2699504 How are you transferring it to AWS?  Using the AWS CLI?  You may be trying to solve a problem that doesn't need solving as they validate file checksums after uploads anyway: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-faq.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot in DS1. The reason is that the maximum variable size that SAS allows is only 32,767 bytes long. You could group the variables in multiple variables, but still when you try to concatenate them (even directly when invoking the md5 function), it will end up truncating it. Your best bet is writing the output to an external text file (as shown below based on your previous example) and generating md5sum on it. This is actually just one little extra step.. You could just use the X command to do that from within SAS itself (provided you are configured to do so).

```
filename ff "contents.txt" TERMSTR=CR;

data _null_;
  set shoes end = lastrec;
  newvar2 = catx(',',&varstr2);
  file ff;
  put newvar2;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the [HASHING_FILE](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/n0n1i6477d9a9in1lflbgj24dx5f.htm) function:

```
data _null_;
    MD5 = hashing_file('MD5',"&thispath\thatfile.xlsx");
    file "&thispath\thatfile.txt";
    put 'MD5:'  MD5;
    putlog 'NOTE: MD5:'  MD5;
run;
```

*Disclaimer: At the time of writing, I still have to test this. If it does not work, I will come back to correct my answer.*